# Why do birth death processes follow detailed balance equations?

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process

I am following a lecture series on Markov Chains from MIT OCW over [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/resources/mit6_041f10_l17/). The lecture (and the notes) state that for birth death processes, the detailed balance equations hold.

$$\pi_{i}P_{ij} = \pi_{j}P_{ji}$$

Here, $\pi$ represents the stationary distribution at some node $i$ and $P$ represents the probability of going from state $i$ to $j$

Comment: Looking at the slides, this does not look like a continuous time birth-death process, studied in [Stephens (2000).](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-1/Bayesian-analysis-of-mixture-models-with-an-unknown-number-of/10.1214/aos/1016120364.full)